# How configure Blazor Web server to listen IP addresses?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I build a Blazor Web app server, run it on machine but it responds on localhost only, i.e.
http://localhost:5000
but does not respond when I query it from an exrternal host
http://myhostIP:5000
This myhostIP pinged ok. FW is off.
In VS2019 in the project settings:
App URL: https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000

How to configure Blazor Web server to listen (all) hosts IP addresses using appsetings.json without hardcoding?

Comment: The question still actual, need help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanx David Fowler:
That's really up to you. You can read custom configuration and set the appropriate URLs or hard code a URL into the application itself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#override-configuration

https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/
https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2017/02/many-different-ways-specifying-host-port-asp-net-core

Answer (score 3):

In my case I've added the entry `https://*:5001` in the file `launchSettings.json` so that it looks like this:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000;https://*:5001"
```

Edit: the launchSettings.json are used only for local development, not if the application is published. Then the started application is not available over network any more. To reach a published app over network you have to define the url in an environment variable or with a [command line argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints) when starting the app:

```
./MyApplication --urls https://*:5000
```

Comment: Which applicationUrl value? There are 3 in the launchSettings file.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I came about this very useful page available [here](https://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/), using netsh, to forward requests.

In short:
Open a command prompt as administrator and replace below command with your IPs / ports:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=192.168.1.100 connectport=3000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

So in this example, all requests that enter your machine for 192.168.1.100:443 are sent to 127.0.0.1:3000

To remove:

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=192.168.1.100
```

Might just be a hack, but working..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1), it is not designed to be used outside localhost. You can use a reverse proxy (like [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/) for instance) to expose your application to the outside world.

Image from MSDN:

[image]

Comment: Yes, Kestrel. But I think you have provided one way. The second way I have tested: copied the app to linux machine, set environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS to machine IP and the site is accessible from an external host. But it is not comfortable for the end-user. I'd like to configure in appsettings.json

Comment: There are other reasons than port sharing why you'd want to use a full fledged web server on top of Kestrel: security, logging, lifetime management, efficient static files handling...

Comment: The question is how to fix even this: http://localhost:5000 - works on the localhost , http://hostIP:5000 - does not work on the localhost

Comment: By the way from the same doc: "Kestrel can be used by itself or with a reverse proxy server"

Comment: Of course it can but it does not provide the features you usually find in a full fledged web server

Comment: Agreed, you are right, but I develop it in VS29019+Win10 and I'd like to provide my server to not advanced  user, which can install it in Mac OSX, run and work. These users do not know about reverse proxies etc ;-)