# How can I run a Blazor App from another device on my local network?

Tags: c#, blazor

I just ran through crating my first Blazor App.  I can run and also debug in Vs Code and Visual Studio using Chrome or Edge.  Now I would like to run the app on other devices on my LAN.  I created a rule for port 5001 in Windows Firewall but I am unable to access my app using my PC's IP address from other devices on my local network.  This is something I have been able to do with other stacks.  Am I missing some configuration step?  Thanks.

Comment: This problem is not related to Blazor. Your issue is that when your web server binds to `localhost` it's not accessible from you local network. This is really the "local host". You need to configure your web server to bind to an IP address or host name so it becomes accessible via the local network. There are several ways to do this and at least one answer that explain a way to do it. Another option is to use a reverse proxy which will proxy network traffic to localhost. This appears to be the solution (ngrok) that you ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I've added the entry `https://*:5001` in the file `launchSettings.json` [as could be seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64520923/9758687)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggestion above but was not able to get it to work.  I finally got the functionality I wanted with ngrok using the command below.

ngrok http https://localhost:5001 -host-header="localhost:5001"

Comment: Ngrok is overkill within a LAN, when the solution is to change the server bind address when running the app

Comment: I used ngrok as I had it alraedy installed. https://davidjones.sportronics.com.au/web/Blazor-Viewing_in_a_phone-web.html  Was simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core) where the problem is explained, basically there are the following steps needed:

- Open your firewall on the specific port
- Specify your IP-address or 0.0.0.0 for all available IP-addresses in Program.cs:

  ```
      public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
          {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
              //webBuilder.UseUrls("https://192.168.120.112:65437");
          });
  ```
- Run the project with Kestrel and **not** IIS-Express

Comment: Opening firewall on port specified in `.UseUrls(...)` did the trick for me!  [Here is how to make appropriet rule](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this just to test on other devices on the LAN, you can actually just use Kestrel directly to serve the Blazor pages, but it won't work over https. See [the microsoft docs on this subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#url-prefixes-1)

That said, you can simply add `http://*:5000` (or whatever other port you want) to the `applicationUrl` property on the `Properties/launchSettings.json` file.

Then the next time you run the project, windows may ask you if you want to allow connections to the app (allowing access to go through the firewall), just press `Allow`. You should now be able to access it on any device on the LAN.

the `launchSettings.json` file may end up looking something like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://*:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```